# How safe is Gitlab for storing encrypted gpg files?

Tags: encryption, gitlab

I'm writing a password manager and I need somewhere to store the encrypted credentials to allow access across multiple devices. Is Gitlab a viable option?

Comment: n·············o

Answer (score 1):

More generally, a Git repository is not a good place to store sensitive information, encrypted or not.
It is a source control made to store history delta and perform diffs (which is not ideal when the versions represent *encrypted* content)

Using a [dedicated vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is safer.